# visualizing a mapping in d3js- model to be used

Tags: json, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize a m:n mapping between two entities in d3js. I want to achieve something like the attached[image: m:n mapping]

I am familiar with d3 force layout for relationships from a central node and the tree diagram and checked out the examples but couldn't find relevant base models. http://techslides.com/over-1000-d3-js-examples-and-demos

What base model should I use to represent a m:n relationship?

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: What is a "base model"? It looks to me you mean an "example"?

Comment: yes- meant something like a force model, tree etc based on which I can build the functionality required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a **Network Diagram**. Check this

- [Dragable network](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4557698)
- [D3 Wiki Gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)
- [Sample Network](http://bl.ocks.org/fhernand/9a9f93f2a6b0e83a9294)

Sankey diagrams are nice to show networks:

[Sankey Diagrams](http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779) - [Editable Sankey to play](http://sankey.csaladen.es)

Some samples with your data:

- [`Here's a Force layout with your data`](https://plnkr.co/edit/k06rufcnFEzOFVrNwjla?p=preview)
- [`Here 's a Sankey Diagram`](https://plnkr.co/edit/1lRltYI5mi35FkDrDLPG?p=preview)